# MySQL can't restore table from backup - #1366 - Incorrect string value

Tags: mysql

A site I'm working on recently had an issue with the database, apparently it got corrupted when they restored the tables any text field with strange symbols (eg half symbol and degree symbol) the text field stopped at the character before that symbol). I've got a copy of the table and distilled it down to the code below:

```
    CREATE TABLE `products2` (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `description` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


    insert  into products2 values  
(25, 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)
```

This throws an error:

```
#1366 - Incorrect string value: '\xBD Digi...' for column 'description' at row 1
```

Looking into this problem on stackoverflow and around the web it seems to be an issue with the encoding, I've tried changing the collation to utf_unicode_ci on the description field and the collation of the table to utf_bin (and all combinations of those) all to no avail.

I can't redo the dump as it's a backup. I don't understand how the system can output the dump but not accept it back - presumably the backup is via the command line (not certain) and I am using PHPMyAdmin to restore it I don't know if that makes a difference.

If it's not possible to import the data I'd be grateful if someone could tell me how to read the encoded data into text that I can then manually cut and paste.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decoding the first 32 bytes as ASCII, we have (where `?` is the `0xBD` byte about which MySQL is complaining):

```
The DPM 912 is a large 3? Digit
```

A little bit of Googling for "DPM 912" [suggests to me](http://www.lascarelectronics.com/pdf-usb-datalogging/data-logger0652731001277711148.pdf) that character should be the vulgar one-half fraction, ½.

[A number of character sets](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00bd/charset_support.htm) encode that character with the byte `0xBD`, but one in particular jumps out: [`windows-1252`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)—which was not only the default codepage in the (pre-Unicode) Windows world, but is also [MySQL's default encoding](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-we-sets.html).  It'd be a good guess that your data is encoded in `windows-1252`.

As explained in [the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-literal.html), you can specify the encoding of a string literal by prefixing it with the encoding name:

> A character string literal may have an optional character set introducer and `COLLATE` clause:
>
> ```
> [_charset_name]'string' [COLLATE collation_name]
> ```

It goes on to say:

> An introducer is also legal before standard hex literal and numeric hex literal notation (`x'literal'` and `0xnnnn`), or before bit-field literal notation (`b'literal'` and `0bnnnn`).

Therefore (and because MySQL refers to `windows-1252` as `latin1`), you could change your `INSERT` command to:

```
INSERT INTO products2 VALUES (25, _latin1 0x5468652044504D203931322069...);
```

The documentation also states:

> For the simple statement `SELECT 'string'`, the string has the character set and collation defined by the `character_set_connection` and `collation_connection` system variables.

That is, if such an introducer is omitted (as it was in your original `INSERT` statement), the character set is assumed to be that defined by the `character_set_connection` system variable.

As mentioned [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-connection.html), there are number of ways of setting that variable (including by specifying it when your client connects which, in phpMyAdmin, is set with the [`[DefaultCharset]`](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#DefaultCharset) configuration option, of which the default was `latin1` prior to v3.4, but has been `utf8` since - perhaps this change is the origin of your problems; one can also specify the character set of import files with [`[Import][charset]`](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#charset_2)).  If one doesn't specify the desired character set upon connecting, issuing any of these commands after connecting but before your `INSERT` command will fix it (you could, for example, add one of them to the top of your dump file):

```
SET NAMES 'latin1';
SET CHARACTER SET latin1;
SET character_set_connection = latin1;
```

My recommendation, which makes the dumpfile as portable as possible, would be to add `SET NAMES 'latin1'` to the top of it.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the table columns to latin1_bin and the table collation and that fixed it.